# The first view of the tab bar controller views in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to change the first view displayed of the tab bar controller without changing its position (the position of its icon in the bar).For example, the scene that is represented in tab bar controller as a symbol in the middle is the scene which I want to display first. could anyone answer me please ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a tab other than the first tab to be the initially selected tab or are you asking how to show a different view in a given tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `selectedViewController` property on UITabBarController to manually select a view controller.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController